# Titanium: ERROR | An uncaught exception was thrown! spawn C:\nodejs\node.exe

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I am trying to run my sample program in appcelerator studio.

i have installed android SDK and node js .

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\apanditi\.appcelerator\install\5.2.0\package\node_modules\alloy\bin\alloy compile F:\Appcelerator\simpleAlloy\app --config platform=android,version=0,simtype=none,devicefamily=none,deploytype=development,target=emulator --no-colors
2016-03-07T07:18:33.959Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
spawn C:\nodejs\node.exe
2016-03-07T07:18:33.959Z | ERROR  | spawn C:\nodejs\node.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe ENOENT
2016-03-07T07:18:33.960Z | TRACE  | Error: spawn C:\nodejs\node.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:441:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
---------------------------------------------
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:281:13)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:362:9)
    at F:\Appcelerator\simpleAlloy\plugins\ti.alloy\hooks\alloy.js:161:14
    at C:\Users\apanditi\.appcelerator\install\5.2.0\package\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\node-appc\lib\async.js:46:6
    at C:\Users\apanditi\.appcelerator\install\5.2.0\package\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:697:13
    at C:\Users\apanditi\.appcelerator\install\5.2.0\package\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:52:16
    at done (C:\Users\apanditi\.appcelerator\install\5.2.0\package\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:248:21)
    at C:\Users\apanditi\.appcelerator\install\5.2.0\package\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:44:16
    at C:\Users\apanditi\.appcelerator\install\5.2.0\package\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:694:17
---------------------------------------------
    at Object.exports.execFile (child_process.js:296:9)
    at exports.exec (child_process.js:111:18)
    at F:\Appcelerator\simpleAlloy\plugins\ti.alloy\hooks\alloy.js:99:7
    at C:\Users\apanditi\.appcelerator\install\5.2.0\package\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:689:13
    at C:\Users\apanditi\.appcelerator\install\5.2.0\package\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:239:13
    at _arrayEach (C:\Users\apanditi\.appcelerator\install\5.2.0\package\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:91:13)
    at _each (C:\Users\apanditi\.appcelerator\install\5.2.0\package\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:82:13)
    at async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (C:\Users\apanditi\.appcelerator\install\5.2.0\package\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:238:9)
    at _parallel (C:\Users\apanditi\.appcelerator\install\5.2.0\package\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:688:9)
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe ENOENT
```

But i have node installed in SDK as well seperately in my system.

Answer (score 1):

Read this below url first,

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Software_Locations_and_Environment_Variables-section-29004844_SoftwareLocationsandEnvironmentVariables-WindowsSoftwareLocations

–> This url contains environment variables setup for titanium applications.

–> Check all environment variables (ex: path) correctly set or not.

–> After setting all environment variables correctly, Restart the studio and rebuild.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue for me by removing one of the versions of nodejs. I had two versions installed. Win 8.1. By the way, I managed to run the command

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\apanditi\.appcelerator\install\5.2.0\package\node_modules\alloy\bin\alloy compile F:\Appcelerator\simpleAlloy\app --config platform=android,version=0,simtype=none,devicefamily=none,deploytype=development,target=emulator --no-colors
```

successfully in a separate `cmd` window during occuring this error in appcelerator studio

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to uninstall one of the versions, actually you just have to look at the PC environment variables and just remove node from path! It might look strange but it indeed solved the spawn ENOENT problem. It happened to me when I installed Platino Studio 1.1 which uses older Node.js version. 
so you can keep both versions installed the 4.0 and the 0.12.7 but just remove their path instance from pc environment variables.
my pc os is windows 10